# Express.js URL encoding of parameters w/ special characters

Tags: node.js, url, express, encoding

I am building an express.js web API and have hit a snag working with our legacy data.  We have identity fields on a particular data model that contains lots of different special characters.  Here are some of our example ids:

```
W2220-059AP0254LL%M031  
SMT II #12B75984  
ST14P134-0110072,9\'98  
TKH-12-110?????
```

So we have an endpoint like:  `/thing/{id}`

Obviously the above examples don't work with this endpoint.  I have tried to do URI encoding in our first entrypoint with express but by the time it hits that it is already too late in most cases.

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: To make it work you need to change id encoding on both client and server sides.

Answer (score 3):

Try this middleware (before any of your routes):

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  req.url = req.url.replace(/^(\/thing\/)(.+)/, function($0, $1, $2) {
    return $1 + encodeURIComponent($2);
  });
  next();
});
```

This assumes that *all* requests to `/thing/:id` are not properly encoded.